# Is it possible to secure an included jsp with spring-security?

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, include, spring-security

I got a jsp which imports a jsp file. Is it possible to secure the import with a spring-security configuration?

For example i want to use this line of code:

```
<c:import url="jsp/admin/add_user.jsp" />
```

But if the user is not logged in as admin than this import should not work because of security reasons. I secured the admin folder with this line

```
<intercept-url pattern="/jsp/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

But when import the add_user jsp in a jsp file where no admin rights are needed than it still works if the user is logged in as an user without the admin role. I prefer not to use tags around the import if this is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Security use a Servlet Filter to ensure secure mechanisms on resources the user is accessing.

When you import a JSP the Servlet Filter can't intercept the call because the resource is loaded internally without passing thru a Servlet connection.

A possible solution is to add logic inside the jsp page that prevent importing of the secure resource if the user don't have necessaries credentials.

I'm not a JSP expert, but I don't see how you can add the necessary logic without adding tag around the import.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by forcing the request to go outside the container. e.g.

```
<c:import url="http://localhost/jsp/admin/add_user.jsp" />
```

However I wouldn't really recommend this. One reason is that in many containers if a 403 is returned from the imported url it will propogate to the parent page and return a 403 for the entire page.

So wrapping the import in some spring security tags may be a better way to go.

Although I'd also consider simply having two separate jsp's - one for admin users and one for non-admin users. If you break down the page into components almost no duplication of content should be required.

Comment: Thanks this works. I do want an 403 error for the entire page since this should not happen on normal site navigation. I don't get a a 403 unfortunately but a nested login form in my current page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="authz"
    uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

----

    <authz:authorize access="hasRole('campaign_read')">   
        Manager login --- <%@include file="manager/create_viewer.jsp"%>
    </authz:authorize>
```

Comment: Use the above spring security tag lib.

Comment: mondev, you can edit your own answers.  Also, please make sure that code is properly tagged using an indent of four spaces.